# Keybinding to make End go one character past the last character on the line

Tags: vim, vimrc

By default the End key takes me to the last character on the line in Vim. However, I have `set virtualedit=onemore` in my vimrc, and I actually want End to take me one character past the last character.

First I tried `map <End> g$` but if the line goes off the end of the screen, it only takes me to the last visible character.

Then I tried `map <End> $<Right>` but if the line is blank it takes me to the next line instead of just doing nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run an expression that checks to see if the line has characters, and acts accordingly. Try this:

```
:noremap <expr> <end> (col('$')>1?"\<lt>end>\<lt>right>":'')
```

See:

```
:help :map-<expr>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
   :map <End> $a<space><ESC>
```

This will move to the last character, then appends a space and then moves to it.

Comment: OP doesn't want to add a space, just move the cursor past the last character on a line, which is possible without adding characters to the file when `virtualedit=onemore`.